# Css for div in the tag TransformComponent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, nested, tags

I have a div with classname grid in the TransformComponent tag.I am trying to apply css to grid through external css by accessing it as .grid{}.But the css is not getting applied to it..grid is the css i am aplying for the div named as grid in transormcomponent tag
Below is the code of .jsx file followed by scss content.
Help would be appreciated.Thank you

```
<div className="zoom">
                        <TransformWrapper
                        defaultScale={1}
                        defaultPositionX={200}
                        defaultPositionY={100}
                        >
                        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, positionX, positionY, ...rest }) => (
                        <React.Fragment>
                        <div className="tools">

                        <button onClick={zoomIn}>+</button>
                        <button onClick={zoomOut}>-</button>
                        <button onClick={resetTransform}>x</button>
                        </div>

                        <TransformComponent >

                        <div className="grid">
                             <input 
                            type="file"
                            className="file"
                            id="file-browser-input"
                            name="file-browser-input"
                            ref ={input=>this.fileInput=input}
                            onDragOver={(e)=>{
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            }


                            }
                        onDrop={this.onFileLoad.bind(this)}
                        onChange={this.onFileLoad.bind(this)}
                        onMouseDown={this.catchItem.bind(this)}
                        //onMouseMove={this.mousemove.bind(this)}
                        //onMouseUp={this.mouseup.bind(this)}

                         />
                        <div 
                        className="files-preview-container" 

                        onMouseDown={this.catchItem.bind(this)}>
                        {loadedFiles.map((file,idx) => {
                            return <div
                                className="file"
                                key={idx}
                                >
                                <img src = {file.data}/>


                            </div>
                        })}
                        </div>


                        </div>
          </TransformComponent>

        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </TransformWrapper>








  </div>


  .zoom{
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        left:15%;
        right:15%;
        height: 93%;
        background-color: palevioletred;

        //background: url("grid.svg");  

            .grid{
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top:30px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            background-color: black;

            background: url("grid.svg");
            }
```

Comment: Can you also put the css you are applying.

Comment: yeah.Check out edited code

Comment: Did you try inspecting the element? see if the class prop is there in the element.
Also are you using simple css or sass modules?

Comment: I am using .scss extensions

Comment: This looks like a scope issue, can you please paste your full css file and also full jsx?

Comment: try adding `!important` to the css

Comment: Adding !important is not the best solution unless we have no other option.

Comment: Did you import the correct CSS in the component?

Comment: where to add !important

Comment: Current Edit has a complete content of .jsx and .scss file